# Appbar button color not persisting till onclick function returns

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, button, appbar

On clicking the contact icon it's background color changes to blue, but immediately returns back to it's original color. I want to keep the background color to blue till the OnClick function returns. I am wonderind if is there any way to it?

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton x:Name="ContactBtn" x:Uid="Contact_id" Icon="Contact" Label="View Contacts" Click="OnClick" />
            </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands> 
       </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style of the button depends on it's VisualState. I think the easiest way would be using a [`AppBarToggleButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbartogglebutton.aspx) and set it's [`IsChecked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx) to `true` during the execution.
The Click sets it automatically to true, so you only need to reset it to `false`.

But that's still not as easy as it sounds. Because this only has an effect if you do some asynchronous stuff in your click event or you open a `Popup` or similar.

If you do only synchronous stuff, the button UI would not be updated. So I think it's already something async.

Comment: Thanks a lot...Your solution worked for me. Using AppBarToggleButton and setting-resetting it's IsChecked property resolved my problem.

Comment: @SanjeevKumar Nice that it helps. It would be nice if you up vote my post and/or select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In start of OnClick method set property IsPressed of your AppBarButton to true, at the end set to false;

**EDIT**

```
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Path=IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}" Value="True">
        <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background" Value="Blue"/>
    </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
    <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Path=IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}" Value="False">
        <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background" Value="Black"/>
    </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

When IsPressed changed you can set background that you want.

Comment: I think this won't work because `IsPressed` has no setter. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.buttonbase.ispressed.aspx
Additionally the code in the `Click` handler must be async.